# QGIS Modeler - drag and drop data from ToC

Tags: qgis-modeler

Is it possible to drag and drop data from the ToC to a graphical modeler and then draw connections between data and algorithms?

Also can we do the same with items in the history panel?

This would speed up the process of creating a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. It is conceivable that such a feature can work by inferring the Input Type from the layer and adding appropriate input in the modeler. However there are cases where this is not optimal. For example, a vector layer can be part of 'Vector Layer' or 'Map Layer' or 'Multiple Input' type. So it may end up confusing some users if a wrong choice is auto-configured.

Drag-and-drop of items from history panel is interesting and can help save time by configuring the parameter values automatically. Feel free to file the feature request at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues